In jetpack compose, how can I quickly display 169 elements at once?
I need to display a table that contains 169 items. Each element is not clickable, but has a border and its own text and color. My code generates the table for quite a long time, about 3 seconds. Really need to make it almost instantaneous.
1)What am I doing wrong and how can this be sped up?
2)Is it not possible to do this via jetpack compose?
3)I probably can't implement xml markup in my code at the same time as compose, right?
At the moment my code looks like this. I've searched a lot, but haven't found any other ways:
@Composable
fun GridOfButtons() {
    LazyColumn {
        repeat(13) { rowIndex ->
            item {
                Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                    repeat(13) { columnIndex ->
                        ButtonBox(index = rowIndex * 13 + columnIndex)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun ButtonBox(index: Int) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(0.dp)
            .size(screenWidth / 16)
            .background(Color.Blue, shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
            .clickable {
            }
            .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Black),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {
        Column (horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally){
            Text (key_to_hand_h[index], fontSize = 12.sp)
            Text(text = index.toString(), color = Color.Black, fontSize = 8.sp)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomDialog(onDismiss: () -> Unit) {
    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
        content = {
            BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier
                //.fillMaxWidth(1.25f)
                //.fillMaxHeight(0.75f)
                .background(Color.Blue)
            ) {
                GridOfButtons()
            }
        }
    )
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I have done 2 things.
1)Tried to make it as a text table
2)Changed the original like this.
In both cases I got a slight speedup. Now, instead of 3 sec, it opens somewhere around 2. But it still takes a long time.
//1).......................
fun TextTable() {
    val textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
    Column {
        for (i in 0 until 13) {
            Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                for (j in 0 until 13) {
                    Text(
//2)........................
@Composable
fun GridOfButtons() {
    LazyColumn {
        items(13) { index ->
            Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                repeat(13) { columnIndex ->
                    ButtonBox(index = index * 13 + columnIndex)
                }
            }
            //ButtonBox(index = index)
        }
    }
}


There is nothing obvious in that code that should take much time. Are you certain that the problem lies there and not elsewhere, such as in the code that gets the data to display?

It's possible. I checked through the inspector. When I click on the button, for the table to appear - other elements do "skipped". Can this affect the display speed?
Why they do that - I don't know. I don't have any dependent "remember" variables that change their state when clicked.

It's a card game. I have a Player() function that gets different states, and displays 10 players. If one of the players changes its state, the other functions should not be affected, because they are generated based on the other states, right? I think there might be a bottleneck somewhere.

Anyway, guys, I've tried a lot of things. 1) I tried initializing elements not immediately, but via LaunchedEffect: "LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
repeat(13 * 13) { index ->
delay(0);
currentIndex = index ;
}
}".........2)Tried the asynchronous code "LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
coroutineScope.launch" ......Nothing helps.

I have minimize the unnecessary nesting and computations, and composables are reused here for the better performance.
@Composable
    fun GridOfButtons() {
        LazyColumn {
            items(169) { index ->
                ButtonBox(index = index)
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Composable
    fun ButtonBox(index: Int) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(0.dp)
                .size(screenWidth / 16)
                .background(Color.Blue, shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Black),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        ) {
            Column (horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally){
                Text (key_to_hand_h[index], fontSize = 12.sp)
                Text(text = index.toString(), color = Color.Black, fontSize = 8.sp)
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Composable
    fun CustomDialog(onDismiss: () -> Unit) {
        Dialog(
            onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
            content = {
                BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Blue)) {
                    GridOfButtons()
                }
            }
        )
    }


Thank you very much for paying attention to my question! Unfortunately, I need to arrange the items in a 13x13 table and have the whole table visible on the screen at the same time.
I have done 2 things. Made changes to my question at the bottom.
1)Tried to make it as a text table
2)Changed the original like this.
In both cases I got a slight speedup. Now, instead of 3 sec, it opens somewhere around 2. But it still takes a long time.

LazyVerticalGrid(cells = GridCells.Fixed(13)) {
items(169) { index ->
ButtonBox(index = index)
}
}
you can try this then

@AlexanderGromov Let me know if this works for you will update the answer.

This works about the same as the previous methods. Maybe the problem is different, like others in the community have said?
I am checking through inspector, I have other recompositions happening with skipped status they may be affecting performance(about 15 items do 1 each)? And why can they happen if I have other variables not changing in any way? The button only changes 1 flag, the flag is only associated with that function call. There are no other changes that occur.

Even if the button only changes one flag, there might be side effects or dependencies within your composable functions that cause recompositions. E.g, if your composable functions rely on external data sources or have some side effects like updating other components, they may trigger recompositions.

What does "composables are reused here for the better performance" mean?

@RyanM Instead of creating individual composables for each item in the grid layout, we reused the same composables for multiple items. Here, the ButtonBox composable is reused for each item in the grid layout

You could try making your grid item composables (ButtonBox) distinct by using the items overload with the key parameter. That would reduce the number of unnecessary recompositions which might be causing your issue.
Try this, f.e.
LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(13)) {
    items(
        count = 169,
        key = {it}
    ) {
        ButtonBox(index = it)
    }                
}

